# Why aren't plastic bottles of coca cola full of microplastics?

Tags: acid-base, plastics

My understanding is that disposable plastic water bottles should not be reused or used at all after some time, because the bottle will eventually leech microplastics into the water. Since coca cola is pretty acidic and can be used as toilet cleaner, doesn't that mean it would "dissolve" its contain bottle and get those microplastics very quickly?

Comment: PET is perhaps not as resistant as PE or PP (which are resistant even to concentrated mineral acids), but is very indifferent to a pH of around 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about two different things and phenomena. One is leaching-which means chemicals in the plastic dissolve into the solution with the passage of time. The other thing is literally physical pieces of microplastics- they are not dissolved but they are actual microscopic pieces of plastic just like very fine dust is present in air. It is not dissolved but it is suspended in air. Coke claims to filter before filling in the bottles. Filtration is an effective way of removing microscopic solids.

Read this report [Microplastics and WHO](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2018/mar/15/microplastics-found-in-more-than-90-of-bottled-water-study-says)

Answer (score 4):

"Microplastic" breaks off from solid plastic material by mechanical wear, often following a degradation of the material by environmental influence like oxygen, light, ...

The *inside* of reusable water bottles does not experience mechanical wear.  Single use bottles even less. Any microplastic particles in there must obviously have come with whatever beverage has been filled in, OR were in there even before, most likely as dust from the plastic bottle factory, or the machine that *cleans* the reusable bottles, where a lot of chips from the battered *outside* fall off.